# Not sure if document.referrer is working

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have some simple JS for redirecting a user away from a page based on a few conditions.

```
   var lastPage = document.referrer; 
   var currentPage = window.location.href;
   var myElem = document.getElementById('topframe.login.label');

        if (currentPage == "https://de.com.edu/webapps/portal/execute/tabs/tabAction?tab_tab_group_id=_1_1")                        
        {
            if (myElem != null && lastPage != "http://www.com.edu/")
            {
                window.location.replace("https://de.com.edu/webapps/login/?action=relogin"); 
            }
        }
```

Basically, if a user ends up on the first link, checked in `currentPage` I want to see if they came from the address `http://www.com.edu` and if not then redirect them using `window.location.replace`.

Problem is this code seems to work no matter what(e.g. user always gets redirected). I have no idea what value `lastPage` is getting and am not seeing any errors in the developer console in Chrome. Is there something dumb that I'm doing wrong? I have confirmed that `http://www.com.edu` is the exact URL I'm looking for and have tried it both with a backslash at the end and without it.

Comment: _“I have no idea what value lastPage is getting”_ – well then disable the redirect, and log that value to console – D’oh!

Comment: change `&& lastPage != "http://www.com.edu/"` to `&& lastPage && lastPage != "http://www.com.edu/"` ; sometimes the referrer is not there for a variety of reasons.

Comment: It's a bad idea to rely on `document.referrer` being anything.

Comment: don't think that testing it once in chrome is enough. there are even different spellings of referrer implemented by some browsers (i'm not kidding), and some don't have it on document, and some block it by default, and some block it based on domain/protocol/content-type...

Comment: If you  use chrome dev tools (or similar) you can set a breakpoint and step through your code. It should then be pretty obvious in your scenario

Answer (score -2):

Here is your solution.Just have to change `null`
Full code:

```
var lastPage = document.referrer; 
var currentPage = window.location.href;
var myElem = document.getElementById('topframe.login.label');

    if (currentPage == "https://de.com.edu/webapps/portal/execute/tabs/tabAction?tab_tab_group_id=_1_1")                        
    {
        if (myElem != '' && lastPage != "http://www.com.edu/")
        {
            window.location.replace("https://de.com.edu/webapps/login/?action=relogin"); 
        }
    }
```

See my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/istiaktridip/qc42n6vq/).